# How to dynamically update client inputs with information from the server - java webapp

Tags: java, web

I created a relatively simple swing application that provides a UI to input data which is then  sent as a SOAP request to a webservice.  The SOAP response is displayed in a large editor pane on the right half of the UI and the textfields and check boxes to create the request are displayed on the left half of the UI.

I need to recreate the same basic app as a web app (I'm thinking java server side so that I can reuse some of my files.)

What I seem to be stuck on is after submitting the form data and creating and sending the SOAP request on the server, how do I display the response xml/string back to the client without changing webpages?

What technologies would be best and simplest to use to achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One such technology I know is Ajax. It will update part of webpage without refreshing whole page.

*"AJAX allows web pages to be updated asynchronously by exchanging small amounts of data with the server behind the scenes. This means that it is possible to update parts of a web page, without reloading the whole page."*